# Javascript same origin policy and Google crome console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Does same origin policy apply when you execute javascript in google crome console utility that came from internet domain locally.
for example what happens if I do this in console.

```
//from facebook.com
alert('javascript')
// we can xhr as well here
```

Comment: If only there was some way to find out...

Comment: @JJJ thnx for downvote. what does ur comment mean?

Comment: If you want to know whether something works in the Chrome console, open the console and type it.

Comment: It's not clear what the code in your question means. `alert()` doesn't perform an AJAX call, so the same-origin policy isn't relevant.

Comment: @Barmar does it have to be AJAX for same origin to take effect. initially I thought __ALL__ non-origin scripts were subject to the policy

Comment: You can access non-origin scripts using a normal `<script>` tag, there's no same-origin policy there. The same-origin policy isn't about remote scripts, you can't access a remote `.html` or `.txt` file with AJAX, either.

Comment: Yes I know that `<scripts>` can be used for that. what I really what to know is, if they is a policy differentiating `alert()` from AJAX calls in context of non-origin script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything you execute from the Chrome console is executed in the context of the web page that you opened it from. So if you try to perform an AJAX call to a different domain from that page, it will be restricted by the same-origin policy.

I opened the console here on SO, and typed:

```
$.get('http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test.html', function(x) {console.log(x);})
```

and I got the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dev.bridgebase.com/barmar_test/test.html?_=1481190195362. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.